# How to use Bootstrap-Vue in a ASP.net project in VisualStudio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

We have a NuGet package for Vue 2.5 so it's easy to set things up in an ASP.net project in Visual Studio 2017, but so far we don't have a Bootstrap-vue NuGet package.

In [Bootstrap-vue website](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/) there are instructions for NPM and YARN only.

What are the steps to add Bootstrap-vue in an ASP.net project in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I just Googled and found your question.

Comment: Not so far, unfortunately....

Answer (score 0):

After quite some time it seems that there will be no Nuget packages for Vue.JS and Bootstrap-Vue, so that's what I did to refactor my ASP.NET MVC application to use Vue.JS and Bootstrap-Vue:

1. I used NPM to manually download both packages add them to the VS project;
2. I refactored the bundles my application uses to include Vue.JS and Bootstrap-Vue;
3. I refactored my views (including layout views) to use Vue.JS and Bootstrap-Vue;

I hope this can be useful to other people.